# Access model association from view

Tags: ember.js

I have user and workspace models with a belongsTo / hasMany relationship:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  workspace: DS.belongsTo('App.Workspace')
});

App.Workspace = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('App.User')
});
```

I have a controller and view setup with the controller's model property set to a valid user.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('test').set('model', App.User.find(1));
  }
});
```

The following code and output shows that the belongsTo association has not been loaded at the time the code is executed. What is the proper way to access the workspace (through the user) from the view class?

```
App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;

    console.log('first try: ');
    console.log(this.get('controller.model.workspace'));

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('second try: ');
      console.log(self.get('controller.model.workspace'));
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Outputs;

```
// first try: 
// null 
// second try: 
// Class { ... }
```

I can access the workspace in the template via {{model.workspace}} — how do I do the same thing in the view class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the proper way to access the workspace (through the user) from the view class?

Your method `this.get('controller.model.workspace')` is the right way to access the workspace from your view. But as your example shows the didInsertElement() hook is the wrong place to do it. Since `App.User.find(1)` is asynchronous, you cannot count on `model.workspace` (or even `model` itself) being available when the template is being rendered. That's why your console.log returns null the first time.

This is perhaps not obvious since Ember works very hard to eliminate explicit forms of asynchronous behavior. Since it returns a model reference right away we might expect `App.User.find()` to be synchronous but it's not. Have a look at [managing-asynchrony](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/managing-asynchrony/) for a closer look at the details.

> I can access the workspace in the template via {{model.workspace}} — how do I do the same thing in the view class?

Behind the scenes, handlebars is binding `{{model.workspace}}` to your model and re-rendering the template when the value changes. You should use a similar technique from your view class. Depending on what you are looking to accomplish, you may want to use a binding, computed property, or an observer. For example:

```
App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({

  workspaceChanged: function() {
    console.log('workspaceChanged to: ');
    console.log(this.get('controller.model.workspace'));        
  }.observes('controller.model.workspace')

});
```

Also see [Bindings. Observers, Computed Properties: What Do I Use When?](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/what-do-i-use-when/)

Comment: Thank you! Thank you for the quick response and the thorough answer. After reading your response and the supporting links I now have a much better grasp of how this Ember thing works :) I've updated my code and it is now working beautifully.